# Export message encounter "The item is opened in read-only mode."

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, exchangewebservices

Recently, When I export message from office365, some messages reply errors:

> ErrorAccessDenied
>
> Access is denied. Check credentials and try again., The item is opened in read-only mode.

1. Is this possibie that user modified the settings on O365 conducting this lock?
2. Or this is just a back-end problem on ews-webservice? because I still can request data from GRAPH API.

Thanks for help!

---

updates @4/15

More information about this kinds of mails, they are all same t:ItemClass:

```
<t:ItemClass>IPM.Note.NotSupportedICal</t:ItemClass>
```

And contain a "not supported calendar message.ics" attachment

```
<t:Attachments>
    <t:FileAttachment>
        <t:AttachmentId Id="XXX"/>
        <t:Name>not supported calendar message.ics</t:Name>
        <t:ContentType>text/calendar</t:ContentType>
        <t:Size>3924</t:Size>
        <t:LastModifiedTime>2016-04-11T14:25:12</t:LastModifiedTime>
        <t:IsInline>false</t:IsInline>
        <t:IsContactPhoto>false</t:IsContactPhoto>
    </t:FileAttachment>
</t:Attachments>
```

So it is obvious that something wrong in MS server side with endpoint
https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/Exchange.asmx